# Accessing the name of a SpatialPolygons object from a list in r

Tags: r, list, for-loop, r-sp

I have created a list of SpatialPolygons objects in r using the below code and wish to run each polygon through a for loop. I would like to access the original name that I assigned to each object so that it can be used within the for loop. This should be really easy but I can't figure out how to do it with a SpatialPolygons object, as there appears to be no information stored in the object once loaded within the for loop that links it to this original name. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
oblist = c(p1,p2,p3,p4)

for(i in 1:length(oblist)){
  obs = oblist[[i]]
  obj.nm = #some way to obtain the original object name i.e. p1 for oblist[[1]]
  …#etc#

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list with named components, rather than a vector:

```
> oblist = list(p1=p1, p2=p2, p3=p3, p4=p4)
> for(i in 1:length(oblist)){
+   print(names(oblist)[i])
+   print(oblist[[i]])
+ }
```

Note that the name of a variable should rarely be of interest to code. This kind of introspection is discouraged. Very few languages allow it. A variable should not be able to ask what its name is. Its only in rare occasions, like when you do `plot(foo,bar)` and you want the axes to be labelled `foo` and `bar`, that you should do it.

Better to have another variable that stores the names of the elements of the objects (and this is how the above code sort of works, by storing their names in the names attribute of a list). This also lets you have names that aren't valid variable names.

Comment: @ Spacedman: Excellent. Thanks! Just what I was looking for. So obvious, I can't believe I missed it!